# MultiDatesPicker disable range days

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

It is posible disabled a range of days in MultiDatesPicker? In the website (http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/) tell that it is posible disable dates from a list, but i need disable the dates higher than a date. It is posible? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an extension of the jQueryUI datepicker, you should be able to pass the [`minDate` and `maxDate` options](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max).

```
maxDate: '2013/05/11' // disable dates after tomorrow (relative to the date of this post)
```

Comment: `maxDate: "+1M 10D"` // disable dates after "in 1 months & 10 Days"